# chrome hijack escape key for vim mode in cloud9 IDE

Tags: google-chrome, vim, cloud9-ide

Using cloud9 IDE in vim mode, when I press ESC key (trying to change vim modes), somehow, it appears that chrome hijack the ESC key and I lose my focus on the IDE. 
Is there a way to work around?
BTW: cloud9 IDE vim mode works fine in safari browser.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed n chrome?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I played around with the extension. And it turns out to be viminum extension. Disabling it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 17):

I find the workaround: using Ctrl-c instead of Escape.